# PHP renaming index files

Tags: php, rename, file-rename

I'm trying to switch index files using PHP and have gone for a method where I rename respective index files, like this:

```
<?php
rename("/index.html", "/REALindex.html");
rename("/index2.html","index.html");
?>
```

The PHP script is located in a folder child of the index files, but when I run this php nothing happens to the files, so I am both wondering how I'm supposed to debug and also why it's not working..?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Post your folder's structure.

Comment: `"/index.html"` is a file locate in the root directory of your drive where, most probably, you cannot write. Use [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) and [`dirname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) to build the paths of the files starting from the directory of the script or simply use `"index.html"` and `"REALindex.html"` (no paths) if the files you want to rename are located in the same directory as the script that attempts to rename them.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/4a5e506ce7819e4d4bf729d684ca0e2f

Comment: its possible that PHP doesn't have permission to rename files on the path you're trying to, if your server is well configured.

Comment: @AlexanderJovric based upon that file structure, try using "../index.html", rather than "/index.html", as i assume the php is one level below the index.html files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your PHP script has permissions to edit the local directories you're running in (based upon the comment you made), your HTML files are one level up from the php, so try:

```
rename("../index.html", "../REALindex.html");
rename("../index2.html","../index.html");
```

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that PHP lacks permission, I will try to fix this and then try your solution! :)

Comment: Did this: chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/php
and tried to suggestion but did not work.. :(. How am I supposed to debug this?

Comment: @AlexanderJovric its the parent directory you want to edit, not /php. try the chmod on `/var/www/html', as those are the files you want edit permissions for, not the php script.

Comment: YES! Works now! Thanks to everyone for the input on this.

Comment: just FYI - using 777 isn't sensible in a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

Note the forward slash at the beginning of the paths. Could it be that this is accidentally and you're unwillingly trying to move files from/to the filesystem root, where they just aren't?

Answer (score 0):

**SOULTION:**

chmod -R 777 /var/www/html

+

```
rename("../index.html", "../REALindex.html");
rename("../index2.html","../index.html");
```